# Indent log4j messages based on their log level

Tags: java, log4j, indentation

Can `log4j` be configured to automatically indent messages with an amount proportional to the message log level? I need to get an output like this:

```
    [2013-09-13 09:38:24,638]  INFO - Processing graph nodes...
    [2013-09-13 09:38:24,640] DEBUG -   Processed node 1...
    [2013-09-13 09:38:24,646] DEBUG -   Processed node 2...
    [2013-09-13 09:38:24,649] DEBUG -   Processed node 3...
    [2013-09-13 09:38:25,948]  INFO - Processed 3 node(s)
```

Comment: Unless someone ends up providing a complete answer that's already built-in to what log4j provides, I'd suggest subclassing `PatternLayout` and manipulating the content of the message based on the log level.  See http://fw-geekycoder.blogspot.com/2010/07/creating-log4j-custom-patternlayout.html for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do that by configuration.  But you should be able to do it by implementing an custom `Layout` class that understands how to implement your indentation scheme.  Then add that to your appender via the configuration file and all of your log messages will be formatted as you want them to be.

Comment: One such implementation is https://github.com/zepheira/tracer. Pass "> " to right shift the log and "< " to left shift.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if log4j provides any such setting. But you can always write a wrapper method which takes the string message and the Log level as input and within it use a switch statement to do different intendation for different levels.

Answer (score 0):

Below link is old but it is working. It extends Layout class but may be helpful to extend PatternLayout class on similar lines.

https://github.com/zepheira/tracer